Custom Shader with URP
I am using a custom shader for a mesh, which is basically a "sight-blocker" to other meshes.
You cannot see the mesh itself and every other mesh behind it is occluded by it.

Now I upgraded the project to the Universal Render Pipeline according to Unitys documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/InstallURPIntoAProject.html
Unfortunatly, the shader appears to be incompatible with the URP, causing the "sight-blocker" to show the pixels of the mesh behind it but moves then aswell when rotating/moving the viewport:

Since I dont have any experience with shaders, could you please support me converting the shader to work with URP (or maybe its a problem to configuration of the URP itself?).
Shader "Custom/InvisibleStencilShader"
{
    SubShader
    {
        // Make sure this shader is rendered before others
        Tags { "Queue" = "Geometry-1" }

        // This pass will write to the stencil buffer
        Pass
        {
            // Disable color buffer writes
            ColorMask 0
            // Write a value of 1 to the stencil buffer
            Stencil
            {
                Ref 1
                Comp Always
                Pass Replace
            }
        }
    }
}

Thanks in advance

That looks like a normal ShaderLab for the built in renderer. I'd recommend you check the shaders in the URP package and find one that uses stencil and try to replicate that functionality. Or check out ShaderGraph.

Also Unity has a system for occlusion culling, if that's what you're aiming for.

I figured it out and wanted to let you know how I solved it in the end.
Basically i found a reference tutorial on urp's stencil buffer here:
https://bdts.com.au/tips-and-resources/unity-create-windows-portals-using-stencils-with-the-universal-render-pipeline-urp.html
The following steps achieve the desired effect:

Put every Mesh that should be occluded on a new layer called "HiddenObjects".

Put the mask Mesh (that occludes the other meshes) on a new layer called "Mask".

Exclude the new created layers from the Rendering on the URP Asset:


Add new Renderer Feature called "HiddenObjects" and "Mask" to the URP Asset with following settings:


Last but not least, add the following shader to the Mask GameObject with a new Material (to hide the mask-mesh):


.
Shader "Custom/StencilMask"
{
    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            ZWrite Off
        }
    }
}

There is one little tradeoff with this solution, but it works for me as good as before: Only Plane Meshes are occluding properly, solid meshes somehow don't work.
The final result looks like this now:

